# Adding an artificial delay in a Spring Security AuthenticationProvider without making a DOS attack easier

Tags: java, spring-security, owasp

[OWASP suggests](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blocking_Brute_Force_Attacks#Finding_Other_Countermeasures) that one possible countermeasure for preventing brute force password guessing is adding an artificial delay when checking passwords.

Setting aside any question about the effectiveness of such an approach vs temporarily locking accounts etc, how would I implement it inside a Spring Security AuthenticationProvider without creating a situation where it becomes easy for an attacker to quickly consume every web server thread? (which is what I imagine would happen if I just added a Thread.sleep() inside the authenticate method)

Comment: A short and random delay shouldn't be that different compared to when there is no delay, in terms of consuming web-server threads I suppose. How big a delay you intend to add?

Comment: rate limit requests to your application on proxy server or load balancer

Comment: Well, I guess I'm assuming that the configured delay would be significantly longer than most legitimate requests to the application take, hence the concern. I can see how in some cases as you say the difference would be trivial...Let's assume that in this case it's not :)

And yes, one could impose a limit on a proxy server or load balancer but that does require one to be deployed and configured which adds complication.

Comment: I though possibly `AsyncContext.start()` would be a viable option though I don't fully understand it at the moment, and https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/05/javaxservletservletrequeststartasync.html makes me suspect it might actually not help much in practice. Perhaps, however, things have changed significantly in the years since then.

Comment: Rate limiting is a reasonably good measure.

Comment: What about treating it like non-blocking io, whereby you maintain a counter for each delayed response and add some time to it each loop iteration? Once a particular counter exceeds the wait time, you allow it to be picked up for response, but in the mean time, you quietly set it aside and move on to other work in the thread. I can elaborate my thoughts a bit more in an answer if you'd find it useful :)

Comment: would be even more effective (in my opinion) to avoid a brute force attack a maximum number of attempts and exceeded a certain period in which you can no longer login, for example de sebagli 3 voltre the password for 5 minutes qualisasi attempt you face it warns you to wait. this would allow you not to have to expose the service to dos attacks but in the meantime allows the utenos to get all the passwords they know (to remind them of the correct one).

Comment: For me you have 3 options: 1- add a rate limiting reverse proxy to prevent an ip to flood you with request.  2- add a specific rejection rule when login fail on you spring security. An example on how it is done:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts .  3- Use a full reactive stack and Spring reactive / Spring security reactive so that you can use the `delay` methods on flux / mono on the authentication process.

Comment: [As described, account lockouts are usually not a practical solution] Perhaps micro-lockouts can be more effective (and a simpliest way). A 3-5s lokout can be a good tricks to deal with brute force attacks.

Comment: Async processing is probably the best solution for this. I just have a funny idea I wanted to share. Assuming you have front end proxy, like nginx. What if you configure your server to listen on two ports and configure your proxy to forward login request to one of them and all other to another. This way you will have separate thread pool (this part is a bit of a speculation) for login requests which will prevent it from affecting the rest of the app in case of a DOS attack.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT 2.0

With the advent of **Servlet 3.0**, support was added for async processing support, it was made simple to add artificial delay.

PROBLEM: intermediate filter that don't support the async processing

SOLUTION: Additional `AttmeptFilter` at base of filterchain, before any incompatible filter sneaks in and apply our logic of adding delay.

In our previous approach we relied on just timeout, that didn't help cause it's terminating request abnormally. In revised approached I keep a map of `AsyncContext` objects with username and host address combination. And A scheduled job keep watch on which of these requests are waited for desired time and dispatches to appropriate destination.

The approach we are currently using is an additional filter where we check the failed number of attempts against a principal with combination of remote host address, once a threshold is meet.

The number of failed attempts are managed by a dedicated service, which listens to  and each `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` and manipulates attempts according the result.

The attempts for specific principal and host address are blocked by the outermost filter with possible minimal checks (without even reaching spring security) for specified time and the blocking time increases with increasing number of failed attempts.

As the remote host and principal combination is blocked, it will not impact genuine user web experience due to account locking and such other solutions.

I have made crude sample application to make the idea clearer for you

check out code at github
https://github.com/yourarj/spring-security-prevent-brute-force

Crude Architectural overview

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I guess what I'm looking for is a way to have something like the filter in your example, except rather than responding 'You need to wait X seconds before retrying' it would just delay the underlying response by X seconds (hence no client would need to handle a new type of response)...Buuuuut, I want to do that without just jamming in a Thread.sleep and risking all the web server's threads being easily consumed by someone triggering a ton of such sleeps.

Comment: I know what you want to do, but as http request works with request per thread model if you want to delay response the serving `server thread` will be blocked, so we came up with above architecture. And if you are concerned with handling different response type, the user could also be redirected to same login page with our message of attempts.

Comment: Yeah, so I thought that there might be a solution using `httpServletRequest.startAsync()` to get away from the request-per-thread model without major architecture changes...But thus far I haven't been able to understand it well enough to make it work ( or perhaps it's just not possible at all for a reason I haven't yet grasped :)

Comment: @MattSheppard I think I found I've deviced something that would be precise `ramban` for your pain. Will update the answer as well as the git repo soon. (Thanks to you for your hint of using `async support` of `Servlet 3.0`). It was a great learning.

Comment: @MattSheppard you can customize delay addition logic, as required by modifying `mr.awesome.spring.springsecuritydemoone.domain.Attempt#attemptFailed` method

Comment: Ah, awesome, that does indeed seem to work - Thanks! It seems what I was missing was that I was that I wasn't calling chain.doFilter after setting the async timeout but rather trying to call dispatch.

Comment: I should mention, in case anyone's coming to try to use this later - You probably actually need also to prevent concurrent async login requests for the same user, otherwise the delay can be overcome by the client sending a lot of parallel requests. I've not tried to flesh it out, but it ought to be possible to impose the delay in such a way that parallel requests don't actually mean you get any additional password guesses per time period on average.

Comment: Oh, actually wait a sec...That's not actually delaying it at all for me...(I was tricked because my unit test started getting through a lot of requests, but that's because there was no delay (facepalm). Basically at https://github.com/yourarj/spring-security-prevent-brute-force/blob/master/src/main/java/mr/awesome/spring/springsecuritydemoone/filter/AttemptFilter.java#L33 you start the async, then set a timeout, but calling chain.doFiler right after just causes the request to be processed right away.

Comment: @MattSheppard When we call doFilter() on the filter chain, only partial response is sent to client, but the request is not yet completed. The request is completed only when the request is timed out with our specified delay. To get better visual explaination we can try hitting the request from a web browser!

Comment: Played with your repo a bit more this morning. In a web browser I can't see any delay occurring (maybe I'm doing it wrong). I added the equivalent to my test project (https://github.com/mattsheppard/async-delay-test/blob/master/src/main/java/DelayFilter.java#L38) and as far as I can tell now that just triggers a ClosedChannelException from jetty... For what it's worth, https://github.com/mattsheppard/async-delay-test/blob/master/src/test/java/TestServer.java is how I'm testing that a delay occurs and jetty threads are not blocked...Happy to hear if that's the wrong test approach :)

Comment: @MattSheppard you `forgot to do doFilter in DelayFilter`. Tried to push fixed code to git but access is denied. Your demo project `async-delay-test` is working fine as expected.

Comment: Hmmm - In https://github.com/mattsheppard/async-delay-test/blob/master/src/main/java/DelayFilter.java#L38 I was intending to take your `username is not null` and `loginAttemptService.canAttemptNow() says false` branches every time (i.e. just always delay for simplicity), which I think never actually calls `chain.doFilter()`. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious and will be super embarrassed shortly :) I just sent you an invite to be able to push to the async-delay-test repo.

Comment: I wonder if we're seeing different output when running that test - I'm seeing a bunch of 'instant' responses which seem unexpected. If you're interested in pursuing it I'm probably going to track further investigation over at https://github.com/mattsheppard/async-delay-test/issues/1 rather than here. Thanks for your efforts in either case :)

Comment: @Mr.Arjun If I wanted to have the delay, but then continue on with completing the filter chain after the delay how would that be done? Would I add a `AsyncListener` and inside of the `onTimeout` method call `chain.doFilter(request, response); event.getAsyncContext().complete();`. Or should that be done in some other way?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56800640/resuming-a-javax-servlet-filter-filter-chain-after-an-async-timeout-when-using-s

Comment: @Mr.Arjun yep this code definitely does not work see https://github.com/yourarj/spring-security-prevent-brute-force/issues/1

Comment: @Luke Thanks for your insights. Have implemented another approach which meets your needs. Have closed the bug. Reach me out if needed. Updated the answer. Thanks