# Resuming a javax.servlet.Filter filter chain after an async timeout when using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-3.0

I would like to add a delay to some requests without holding onto a thread under jetty. I think this can be done using the asynchronous support added to servlet 3.

I have inside of my filter, which is the first filter to run, something that adds the delay:

```
AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync();
asyncContext.setTimeout(1000L);
```

that appears to delay the request but I am not sure how to to resume the filter chain. I would like to resume the filter chain when the timeout times out.

I tried to add a listener:

```
asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {
@Override
public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(event.getAsyncContext().getRequest(), event.getAsyncContext().getResponse());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

It looks like the next Filter in chain was called but I don't think spring was happy with that. For some request I got no errors but for the login API I always got a 401 yet my code which checks authentication was not called. In other cases I saw a null pointer exceptions:
2019-06-28 13:27:08,772 [admin-78] [::] WARN  advice.CatchAllException - Catching

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.util.StringUtils.uriDecode(StringUtils.java:724)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.decode(UriUtils.java:342)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeInternal(UrlPathHelper.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.decodeRequestString(UrlPathHelper.java:455)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getContextPath(UrlPathHelper.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinApplication(UrlPathHelper.java:239)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getPathWithinServletMapping(UrlPathHelper.java:192)
        at org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(UrlPathHelper.java:169)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:365)
```

How can I continue on with the filter chain?

Comment: I think once a request object is read after your delay it cannot be built again so it cannot be read again. This might be the reasons of your null pointer exceptions. You can try to store all http request info in memory and then after the delay try to build a mock request object in order to resume with the filter chain. But it will not be easy to do so, in most cases it is better to reconsider why you need to delay the request. Besides when you delay the request, how you send the consequent response to the client will be another problem.